# How do I remove trailing space from data being fed into my email with AmpScript?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

IT is passing data a field through an API that has an extra space at the end. This space is causing our unsubscribe link not to work and so we have had to stop all of our emails.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're looking for the [trim()](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/utilities_ampscript_functions/#Trim) AMPScript function.  If you have a personalization string called `string1` as a column in your sending data extension or as a profile attribute, then the syntax would be

```
%%=trim(string1)=%%
```

Or if you have an AMPScript variable string named `string2` that you've set with some scripting (e.g. `set @string2 = "whee"`), then the syntax would be:

```
%%=trim(@string2)=%%
```